# Authenticate a python application in VM with Managed Service Identity(MSI)

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to use MSI example provided in below link :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-python#mgmt-auth-msi

To do that, I created a linux VM , installed MSI extension on it and running above code in a python application and when I run that python application I get the following error:

```
[azureuser@vish-redhat ~]$ python msi-auth.py 
No handlers could be found for logger "msrestazure.azure_active_directory"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "msi-auth.py", line 10, in <module>
    subscription = next(subscription_client.subscriptions.list())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrest/paging.py", line 121, in __next__
    self.advance_page()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrest/paging.py", line 107, in advance_page
    self._response = self._get_next(self.next_link)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/mgmt/resource/subscriptions/v2016_06_01/operations/subscriptions_operations.py", line 207, in internal_paging
    request, header_parameters, **operation_config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrest/service_client.py", line 191, in send
    session = self.creds.signed_session()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrestazure/azure_active_directory.py", line 685, in signed_session
    self.set_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrestazure/azure_active_directory.py", line 681, in set_token
    self.scheme, _, self.token = get_msi_token(self.resource, self.port, self.msi_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrestazure/azure_active_directory.py", line 590, in get_msi_token
    result = requests.post(request_uri, data=payload, headers={'Metadata': 'true'})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 108, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))
[azureuser@vish-redhat ~]$
```

Code:

```
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import MSIAuthentication
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient, SubscriptionClient

# Create MSI Authentication
credentials = MSIAuthentication()


# Create a Subscription Client
subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(credentials)
subscription = next(subscription_client.subscriptions.list())
subscription_id = subscription.subscription_id

# Create a Resource Management client
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)


# List resource groups as an example. The only limit is what role and policy are assigned to this MSI token.
for resource_group in resource_client.resource_groups.list():
    print(resource_group.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need install Python SDK in your Linux VM. Please refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-install?view=azure-python).

```
pip install azure
```

Also, you need give Owner role for your VM on subscription level.

[image]

More information about this please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/tutorial-linux-vm-access-arm).

Now, you could use this code to test on VM. I test in my lab, it works for me.

[image]

Note: You need modify `resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)` to `resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, str(subscription_id))`, it requires a string type.

Comment: i have pip installed azure package already..I think which is why I dont get import error and instead getting connection error. My code is not reaching resource_client assignment line. It's failing at subscription = next() line

Comment: @ForeverLearner I test in my lab, I also met this error. It means you don't give `Owner` role on your subscription level. Check my answer step 2. Because if you don't give owner role, the code does not have permission to get subscription, so you will get the error log.

Comment: But  Honestly say, your error log seems is not this issue. If possible, you could update your question, I will try my best to help you solve it.

Comment: there is already an IAM role representing my user email address to be an owner and scoped to resource as well as subscription level.

Comment: No, you add this VM as `Owner` role, not just your e-mail address. See my screenshot `assign access to Virtual Machine` not `Azure AD user, group or application`.

Comment: See this link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/tutorial-linux-vm-access-arm#grant-your-vm-access-to-a-resource-group-in-azure-resource-manager

Comment: After you give the role, you will see like this screenshot  https://imgur.com/a/fs7eV

Comment: Ok. So I gave permissions as you suggested. Screenshot : https://imgur.com/PdLdVEV. However i get empty resource group list hence could do not output anything .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168159/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-foreverlearner).

Comment: Do you give the role on subscription level or just resource group level?

Comment: I guess you don't give owner role on subscription level, if you do this, I am sure you will list all resource groups in your subscription.

Comment: Yep, so so far I have provided it the following permission. Snapshot: https://imgur.com/2hiK0Wn. Yet I dont get any list of resource groups.

Comment: It is very strange, if possible, could you use `curl` to test it. See this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/tutorial-linux-vm-access-arm#get-an-access-token-using-the-vms-identity-and-use-it-to-call-resource-manager

Answer (score 1):

A connection error is usually because the extension is not yet available. You can try if the extension is available using the CLI with `az login --msi`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/how-to-use-vm-sign-in

If it works, your VM is created correctly with MSI support. It it doesn't, probably your extension is not configured correctly.

Note that we changed the way to get a token with MSI from inside a VM. We now use IMDS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service

Starting with the next release of the CLI (the first one of April 2018), CLI will authenticate with IMDS directly and not use the VM extension anymore. This is already shipped in the underlying library `msrestazure` in its 0.4.25 version. This one will bypass completely your VM extension to use IMDS and is the prefered scenario now. Could you try with this version of `msrestazure`? If it works with 0.4.25 but not in 0.4.24, this likely means your VM extension is not installed correctly, but you don't care since it's a deprecated scenario :)

Note that in order to get a token, your VM doesn't need any special permissions or ownership of subscription. However, for this token to be useful you need it :). But since your error is related to the "get a token" part and not permission, I would just kindly suggest that you might need this complementary info for later if you have permissions issues:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/howto-assign-access-cli

(full disclosure, I work at MS in the SDK/CLI team and wrote the MSI support)

Comment: And yes, NightOwl888 and Shengbao, I tried to be helpful, but I had like 20 seconds to do my first answer and it was too rushed. My apologies.

Comment: az login --msi fails.  It spits error: MSI: Failed to retrieve a token from 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token' with an error of '{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Identity not found"}'

Comment: This uses IMDS, considering the internal IP. My current guess is then that your VM is not MSI enabled. Try to re-enable MSI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/qs-configure-cli-windows-vm#enable-msi-on-an-existing-azure-vm

Comment: Your guess is true. It wasn't get properly enable. After reenabling I get different error though. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "msi-auth.py", line 10, in <module>
    subscription = next(subscription_client.subscriptions.list()) .....File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrest/paging.py", line 105, in advance_page
    raise StopIteration("End of paging")
StopIteration: End of paging

Comment: I don't think so, the error means you don't have enough permission. If your MSI service is not running, you will get error in `credentials = MSIAuthentication()`. To check this, what is the result `netstat -ant|grep 50342` and use `curl http://localhost:50342/oauth2/token --data "resource=https://management.azure.com/" -H Metadata:true` to get token.

Comment: Yes, this error means indeed that it works, you got a token, but you have no subscriptions attached to to that token (`next` on an empty list will always raise a `StopIteration` error)